# AngularJS: ng-click working in Firefox but not in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-chrome

Hello I'm trying to bind a click event to a function in my controller using `ng-click`. it works fine in Firefox, but in chrome nothing happens. When I look at the console no error appear.

Here is my `html`:

```
<div ng-controller="localTripsCreatorController" ng-switch="currentPage">
<div ng-switch-when="generalInfo">
    <!--first page-->
</div>

<div ng-switch-when="program">
    <!--second page-->
</div>
<div>
    <button ng-click="previous()" class="btn btn-normal">Précédant</button>
    <button ng-click="next()" class="btn btn-normal" style="float: right">Suivant</button>
</div>
```

here is my `javascript` :

```
dashboardApp.controller('localTripsCreatorController',function($scope){

console.log("I'm outside click event");

$scope.next = function(){
    console.log("I'm inisde click event");

}

$scope.previous = function(){
    console.log("I'm inisde click event");
}
})
```

My `ng-app` is already declared previously, I do only get `I'm outside click event` printed out in the console. 
Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a wizard using AngularJS.

So any idea why is this working on Firefox but not in chrome?

Comment: It should be working. Check [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9kD7TNUdHZQR5bwLhDOT). Btw, a closing `</div>` tag is missing in html code.

Comment: it is working, but in Firefox

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your button div is not properly binding with the controller.

```
<div ng-controller="localTripsCreatorController" ng-switch="currentPage">
    <div ng-switch-when="generalInfo">
        <!--first page-->
    </div>

    <div ng-switch-when="program">
        <!--second page-->
    </div>
    <div>
        <button ng-click="previous()" class="btn btn-normal">Précédant</button>
        <button ng-click="next()" class="btn btn-normal" style="float: right">Suivant</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or if it is binding correctly, try to bypass that issue; you could make a div, style it to look like a button, then inside the div keep your separate span tags with the click events.

```
<div class="styleLikeButton" >
<a ng-click="previous()" class="btn btn-normal" > Précédant </a>
<a ng-click="next()" class="btn btn-normal" style="float: right"> Suivant </span>
</div>
```

^^ this would work cross-browser, and still keep your "button" functioning.